# Why update statement only sets for one value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have the following two tables;

```
PRICE_TABLE             FACT_TABLE
P_ID                    P_ID
1                       0    
2                       0
3                       0
...                     ....
```

I want to update the `FACT_TABLE` `P_ID` with the corresponding values from the `PRICE_TABLE`. I try with an update statement;

```
UPDATE FACT_TABLE SET P_ID = pt.P_ID FROM PRICE_TABLE AS pt
```

But this just puts the first value into all rows in the `FACT_TABLE`.

```
FACT_TABLE
    P_ID                    
    1                           
    1                       
    1                       
    ...
```

Comment: Is there an indentifier to link the records or do you just want to update the IDs in their storage order (which is not necessarily the same in both tables)

Comment: There is no common identifier other than the ID fields themselves - I intend to have the ID in FACT as foreign keys later on but for now just trying to populate them.

Comment: To just make FACT_TABLE the same as PRICE_TABLE (temporary solution):                              TRUNCATE TABLE FACT_TABLE; INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE SELECT P_ID FROM PRICE_TABLE ;

Comment: I have tried that approach also, however my completed FACT table will have multiple IDs from different tables and I can not seem to add them all in at once.

Comment: you can repeat this part over and over again, just change the PRICE_TABLE to the other table names, one at a time:   INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE SELECT P_ID FROM PRICE_TABLE ;

Comment: (do not repeat the TRUNCATE statement, it cleans out the table--only do that part 1 time)

Comment: Thanks alot I'll go with this approach

Comment: Sounds good. Be careful with TRUNCATE it destroys the data on whatever table you use it on.